# Product with Serializable - reason for

Tags: scala

The following:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
val saveLineValues1 = ListBuffer(("Apple", "Banana"), ("Orange", "Pineapple", "Kiwifruit"))
```

shows:

```
saveLineValues1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Product with Serializable] = ListBuffer((Apple,Banana), (Orange,Pineapple,Kiwifruit))
```

What impact does it have on processing? Cannot see any reasonable explanation for this. I understand the SO 37477709 thread, but not so here. Beacuse I did not state a class? I think a lot of people are using SCALA without understanding some aspects, like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of first element in your list buffer is `scala.Tuple2` which is a subtype of `Product with Serializable`

Type of second element in your list buffer is `scala.Tuple3` which is a subtype of `Product with Serializable`

The final result is ListBuffer of `Product with Serializable` which is the common super type of Tuple2 and Tuple3

> All case classes and tuples are sub type of Product with serializable

Comment: Got it! Strange names.